# TinyMCE is missing

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm not sure why, but all of a sudden TinyMCE stopped showing. It's working to an extent. It's hiding the textarea, but it's not showing the TinyMCE interface. **I don't get any jQuery/Javascript errors.** I'm not sure what's going on or how to start trying to figure it out.

It's just a standard installation. I also have jGrowl, and Selectbox and made changes to them recently. Maybe those are causing it?

Ever heard of them causing problems??

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Load TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.tinymce').tinymce({
// Location of TinyMCE script
script_url : 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

// General options
theme : "advanced",
plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

// Theme options
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fullscreen,code,preview,print,cleanup,|,undo,redo,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,media,template",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,fontsizeselectbullist,numlist",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,advhr,|,|,ltr,rtl,|,insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute",
theme_advanced_buttons4 : "styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,hr,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,styleprops,attribs",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
theme_advanced_resizing : true
});
});
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE --></head>
<body>
<textarea name='body_content' rows="15" cols="80"  class="tinymce" style='height: 400px; width: 75%;'> 
</textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: make sure you are actually loading the jquery file for tinymce (use firebug for this), and make sure it's not corrupted (try redownloading it).

Comment: It worked just fine before and I never touched the .js for TinyMCE. Again, firebug throws no errors.

Comment: can you post the html and the jquery inside that document (or external scripts)?

Comment: ok, i can offer the following suggestion:
when it comes to tinymce, be sure to use textareas. i looked for that word but could not find it. if that is not the reason, i may be able to offer more ideas tomorrow when i have access to my tinymce code.

Comment: This isn't a review my 10001 lines of code site, don't need to post **that** much code!

Comment: Thanks Jakub, you're extremely helpful. I didn't say "Hey, read everything." I just posted my code. Sometimes you don't know what is effecting it until someone comes along and points out something random and totally unrelated that seems to be making it screw up.

Comment: As far as the textareas thing goes. I am using one, I just don't have it targeting it. I have it target all fields with the class tinymce.

Comment: I shortened it up so it's only pertinent code...

Comment: another thing i saw was $().ready(function() {
try $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I don't think that's it because like I said before, it worked at one point, and it also is still converting the textarea to visibility: hidden;

Comment: This attempt to get help may be futile because realistically, without you reading through 90% of my code, I don't know if you will find the problem. It didn't start until recently, and the only thing I've been working on is other plugins, but without a javascript error it's hard to figure out.

Comment: see if you can temporarily remove some of the code (without breaking it of course); you may be able to find out what is causing the problem. do it in small chunks and see if you can find out what the problem is.

try removing some of the plugins as well, one at a time. it's possible there are conflicting settings/plugins.

Comment: That's what I tried, but I realized everytime I removed a plugin's source, I have to remove all the rest of the code that relies on it or it causes a javascript error and obviously then I wouldn't know if tinymce is working again. So this is gonna take a while if you remember seeing all the plugins i'm using lol. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Partial breakthrough! I logged out of FB and it showed up. So it has something to do with my FB integration.

Comment: @Shane Stebner: please let us know if you find out more